# Firefox Performance Call Tree functions IDLE

Tags: performance-testing, firefox-developer-tools

I would like to know in **"firefox devtools / performance / call tree"** what means **functions:IDLE** and how to understand the meaning of a long time in that function.

What could be my next steps to solve delay problems in **functions:IDLE**?

[image: performance idle]

Answer (score 0):

At https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance/Call_Tree

One thing to be aware of here is that idle time is classified as Gecko, so parts of your profile where your JavaScript isn't running will contribute Gecko samples. These aren't relevant to the performance of your site.